# Running adb commands from android application

Tags: java, android, adb

How to run `adb shell am` commands from within an android application. I tried to run dumpheap command. `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("am dumpheap -n 3554 /sdcard/memory");`. I am getting the following error.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Requires permission android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.dumpHeap(ActivityManagerNative.java:3548)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runDumpHeap(Am.java:721)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:124)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:81)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to give required permission in Manifest file. Though from docs it looks like it is only for debug purpose.

You can view the details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER).

Comment: The SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER permission is not allowed for third party applications.

Comment: Yes you need to Sign it with the same cert as the system which is not possible I guess for normal developer. See the thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/OvCcdvO6jZY

Comment: Is there an api equivalent for `dumpheap -n <PID> <FILE>` command?